# Normalizing a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, normalization

I want to normalize my dataframe but normalization should be done every 16 rows where I have 16*1550 rows and 17 columns.
I implemented that using the following code and it is giving a warning. Is this the correct way to do it?

```
for n in range(1550):

     data_features[16*n:16*(n+1)][:] = (data_features[16*n:16*(n+1)][:] - data_features[16*n:16*(n+1)][:].mean())/data_features[16*n:16*(n+1)][:].std()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You will find here nice answer, provided that your questions respect our rules. As a new user, you should read [ask] to know them. Specifically, when you get an error or a warning you are supposed to give the exact error message that contains a lot of information. Ideally, you should try to build a [mcve] with a sample of data to allow other to reproduce. In fact *just enough code and data to reproduce the problem*. That way you will get fixed and tested code in the answers.

Comment: I want a partition, normalizing 0-15 values, then 16-31 and so on..

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you access the dataframe is wrong. To modify **cells** you must always use `loc` or `iloc` (or, if relevant, `at` and `iat`) and NEVER select rows from a column. And if you want to normalize by blocs, you should process rows by blocs. So a simple fix could be:

```
for n in range(1550):
    data_features.iloc[16*n:16*(n+1)] = (
        data_features.iloc[16*n:16*(n+1)]
        - data_features.iloc[16*n:16*(n+1)].mean()
        )/data_features.iloc[16*n:16*(n+1)].std()
```